# n number of x on the y

Tags: python, strings, template, 99-bottles-of-beer

Everyone knows "99 bottles of beer on the wall".

[Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug) made a [comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23528511#23528511) about mugs on the wall in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and I realized I never wrote a "beer on the wall" program. But that seemed way too easy, so I made it a "n number of x on the y" instead. It also seemed like a good excuse to use templates in Python, which I hadn't done before.

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])
x = sys.argv[2]
y = sys.argv[3]

template = '''\
%i %s on the %s
%i %s
Take one down, pass it around
%i %s on the %s
'''

for n in range(n, 0, -1):
    print template % (n, x, y, n, x, n-1, x, y)
```

Usage:

```
python script.py 99 "mugs of beer" wall
```

For obvious reasons there's no way (that I know of) to remove multiples of `x` if `n = 1`. Sure, it's not hard to turn `mugs of beer` into `mug of beer`, but it's generic. One can input anything and I can't catch all methods of pluralization.

I prefer readability over 'clever code' and my naming is probably not too good.

Comment: `n number of x on the y` is mainly there because the title would be too short otherwise. It's actually `n x on the y`

Comment: For the record, "mugs on the wall" is referring to the number of rep points by which I'm ahead of [Simon André Forsberg](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg). There's been "simons on the wall" for the longest time though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is simple and just works. For that reason, you can be happy and there is not much comment to give. However, being very picky just for the sake of learning, one could say various things.

**`print` statements**

You are using `print` without parenthesis. This is the one and only reason why your code wouldn't work on Python 3. Just to be future (well, actually Python 3 is not the future, it is the present) proof, you might as well add the 2 parenthesis.

**String formatting**

Instead of using the `%` format, you could use the `format` method. You'll find more information [online](https://pyformat.info/). Also using named place holder makes things easier to read and avoid duplicated values.

You'd get something like :

```
template = '''\
{idx} {x} on the {y} 
{idx} {x}
Take one down, pass it around
{prev} {x} on the {y}
'''

for n in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(template.format(idx=n, prev=n-1, x=x, y=y))
```

**Error handling**

You should probably check the number of arguments provided and tell the user if anything is wrong.

**Variable names**

Even though `n` is acceptable, `x` and `y` do not convey much information, a better name can probably be found.

Answer (score 8):

I would take [@Josay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9452/josay)'s suggestion one step further, and use more self-descriptive template parameters:

```
template = '''\
{num} {things} on the {where}
{num} {things}
Take one down, pass it around
{remaining} {things} on the {where}
'''
```

And command line argument validation can be really easy using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser    

template = '''\
{num} {things} on the {where}
{num} {things}
Take one down, pass it around
{remaining} {things} on the {where}
'''

parser = ArgumentParser(description='N number of THINGS on the WHERE')
parser.add_argument('num', type=int, help='For example 99')
parser.add_argument('things', help='For example "mugs of beer"')
parser.add_argument('where', help='For example "wall"')

args = parser.parse_args()

num = args.num
things = args.things
where = args.where

for n in range(num, 0, -1):
    print(template.format(num=n, remaining=n-1, things=things, where=where))
```

This will take care of validating the number of arguments,
and that `num` is an integer, for example:

> ```
> $ python3 beers.py 99 'mugs of beer'
> usage: beers.py [-h] num things where
> beers.py: error: the following arguments are required: where
> $ python3 beers.py 99x 'mugs of beer' wall
> usage: beers.py [-h] num things where
> beers.py: error: argument num: invalid int value: '99x'
> ```

And by passing the script the `-h` or `--help` flags you get a nice descriptive usage message:

> ```
> $ python3 beers.py 99 'mugs of beer' -h
> usage: beers.py [-h] num things where
>
> N number of THINGS on the WHERE
>
> positional arguments:
>   num         For example 99
>   things      For example "mugs of beer"
>   where       For example "wall"
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
> ```

Comment: The link for Python (not Python3) is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html), but it seems the usage is the same. I wasn't aware there was a better argument handler than `sys`, I'm definitely going to implement this in my current and future projects.

Comment: Using `sys` was not considered a good option since Python 2.3, when [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) was released. `optparse` used to be the favored solution until 2.7, when it was superseded by `argparse`

Answer (score 6):

You should use `str.format` instead, because you can re-use parameters that way.

```
template = '''\
{0} {1} on the {2}
{0} {1}
Take one down, pass it around
{3} {1} on the {2}
'''

for n in range(n, 0, -1):
    print (template.format(n, x, y, n-1))
```

I think this is more readable than 6 parameters in a row. I also added brackets around your print because it's neater and forward compatible.