# Find all needles in the haystack and return their sum

Tags: python, python-2.x, regex, file

*This is based on a programming challenge I recently solved. However, since the writer of the challenge asked me not to disclose the question and/or it's answer, I modified it a little. If it doesn't make sense: my mistake.*

The target is to find all numbers in a file and sum those. So if the following is found:

```
Sed ut 11 perspiciatis, unde omnis 11 iste natus 20 error sit
```

The result should be `42`.

Floats like `0.42` will be considered equal to `42` in this challenge.

To generate example input, I took the revised version of my ['n x on the y' generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101389/n-number-of-x-on-the-y) and made it run from 999. That's almost 5k lines of code, a nice amount to test against. The old code produces the same output, for those interested.

I was quite content with the performance. Now I'm wondering whether I could've written it better. Readability and maintainability are key, as usual.

The next iteration of this code will likely try to match keywords instead of arbitrary numbers. More on that in a later question.

#### haystack.py

```
# Sum all numbers in a haystack
import re


def getNumbers(inp):
    with open(inp, 'r') as f:
        return re.findall('[0-9]+', str(f.readlines()))

def calculateSum(results):
    total = 0
    for result in results:
        total += int(result)
    return total

def main(input_file='haystack.txt'):
    print calculateSum(getNumbers(input_file))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Any advantage of using `'[0-9]+'` over `r'\d+'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- Use `sum`.
- Make `calculateSum` do one thing. Also instead you could use `sum(int(i) for i in ...)`.
- You can use `re.finditer` to get better memory performance.
- You can use [`mmap.mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html), to reduce memory usage. 5K lines is a lot.
  <sub>Note: It will error on empty files in Windows.</sub>

This can get you:

```
import re
import mmap

def get_matches(data):
    return (g.group(0) for g in re.finditer('[0-9]+', data))

def main(input_file='haystack.txt'):
    with open(input_file, 'r+') as f:
        data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
        return sum(int(i) for i in get_matches(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print main()
```

In the next iteration you can change only `get_matches` to handle the keywords, rather than arbitrary numbers.
And you can iterate over data, one char at a time.

Comment: There's some differences between Unix-mmap and Windows-mmap, but I think I can use it in a relatively platform-independent manner. Neat!

Answer (score 3):

First, you should have a look at PEP8 again, specifically the part about [function names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names). It recommends using `lower_case_with_underscores`. It also recommends leaving two blank lines between function definitions on the module level.

Next, `open` already opens the file read-only by default, there is no need for `'r'`. Also, `f.readlines()` returns a `list`, which you then convert into a string representation of that list. However, you can just use `f.read()` here, which directly returns the full string. Note that reading in the full file content at once might be quite memory-consuming, so don't do it with files larger than your RAM.

Last but not least, your function `calculate_sum` could just be the built-in `sum`, if the elements of `results` were already numbers. So I would change `get_numbers` to return actual numbers (like the name implies), by using `map`:

```
import re

def get_numbers(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', f.read()))


def main(file_name='haystack.txt'):
    print sum(get_numbers(file_name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

In Python 3.x, you could use the `yield from` keyword to make your `get_numbers` into a generator and avoid the memory issue, because the file is read one line at a time (at the cost of executing the regexp for every line):

```
def get_numbers(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield from map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', line))
```

In Python 2.x this could be implemented like this:

```
def get_numbers(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            for item in map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', line)):
                yield item
```

Comment: Since `map` returns a list in Python 2, and you talk about memory issues, you may want to mention `itertools.imap`.

Comment: You'd think I'd know the PEP8 by now. Sorry :-)

Comment: The generator you mention would solve the memory problem, but I suppose  a simple `for line in f` would do the same?

Comment: @Mast That is already what I'm doing there?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Not sure `imap` will make it any better, since it will be read into memory once with the `read` and then deleted and the map is read into memory.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't figure out why you'd need the generator to fix the memory problem. The `for .. in` already takes care of that, right? Your answer reads like it's the generator taking care of that instead of the iteration. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I agree that, compared to the size of the file, avoiding to copy the list produced by `findall` is minimal. But if the haystack is mainly composed of needles, it can help.

Comment: You can do this in whatever \$O\$ the regex is. If you look at my answer. Mostly as `for line in file` could be the entire file.

Answer (score 2):

You could significantly shorten your code while speeding it up using [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) and built in python functions.

```
data = 'Sed ut $11 perspiciatis, unde omnis 11hours and 22mins iste natus 20 error sit' #11+11+22+20 = 64
```

**Method 1**

```
n = []
for i in data.split(' '): #we split the list at each index of ' '
    if i.isdigit(): #built in method to determine if an object can be an int
        n.append(int(i)) #append to list
```

**Method 1.2**

List comprehension

```
n = sum((int(i) for i in data.split(' ') if i.isdigit()))
```

**Output**

```
print n #--> 20, because it dosen't find $11, 11hours, 22mins
```

**Method 2**
Using `re` we modify the pattern of `Method 1.2`

```
import re
n_2 = sum((int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', data)))
```

**Output**

```
print n_2 #--> 64 finds all.
```

Comment: Method 1 and 1.2 also fail to parse `0.41` as `41`, as specified.

Comment: @Graipher Yes that is correct, it also fails on the decimal portions. i was only showing the first to show the alternate methods and steps I would take to solve the problem. `Method 2` passes on both and the only thing that changes is our condition,